# PUT http://localhost:8080/api/TransferProduct/2 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED, ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

i have various product on the DB and i want to change to ownership and location of the product but i am unable to do that.
In frontend i have used RecatJS
My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../all.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const TransferProduct = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        id: "",
        oname: "",
        area: ""
      });
    
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value;
        setData({
          ...data,
          [e.target.name]: value
        });
      };
    
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const userData = {
          
            id: data.id,
            owner: data.oname,
            area: data.area
        };
        axios
          .put("http://localhost:8080/api/TransferProduct/"+data.id, userData)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
              console.log(error.response);
              console.log("server responded");
            } else if (error.request) {
              console.log("network error");
            } else {
              console.log(error);
            }
          });

      };
return (
    <div>
             <form method="post">
        <label htmlFor="header-search">
            <span className="visually-hidden">From</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="id" value={data.id}  placeholder="ID" onChange={handleChange}
/>
          <label htmlFor="header-search">
            <span className="visually-hidden">TO</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="oname" value={data.oname}  placeholder="Enter New Owner"  onChange={handleChange}
 />

<label htmlFor="header-search">
            <span className="visually-hidden">TO</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="area" value={data.area}  placeholder="Enter new Location"  onChange={handleChange}
 />

        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>Transfer</button>
    </form>

    </div>
);
};

export default TransferProduct;
```

and in backend i have used Nodejs
my code:

```
    app.put('/api/TransferProduct/:id', async function (req, res) {
    try {
    const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'dev','fabric-samples','test-network', 'organizations', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'connection-org1.json');
    const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));
     
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
    const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);
     
    const identity = await wallet.get('appUser');
    if (!identity) {
    console.log('An identity for the user "appUser" does not exist in the wallet');
    console.log('Run the registerUser.js application before retrying');
    return;
    }
     
    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccp, { wallet, identity: 'appUser', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });
     
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork('testchannel');
     
    const contract = network.getContract('supply_chain');
     

     
    await contract.submitTransaction('TransferProduct',req.params.id,req.body.newOwner,req.body.newArea);
    console.log('Transaction has been submitted');
    res.send('Transaction has been submitted');
     
    await gateway.disconnect();
     
    } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to evaluate transaction: ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
    }
    });
```

in screenshot one there is list of all products and in screenshot 2 there is error i am getting while transferring the products
[image: list of products i have]

[image: error i am getting while transferring the ownership]

Comment: Don't concatenate errors (`"blah " + error` / `\`blah ${error}\``), you will lose the valuable stack information. If you really _have_ to, use `error.stack`, but it's better to just log it as separate argument (`"blah", error`) because this will also include additional properties such as `code` in the output. In your case: `console.error('Failed to evaluate transaction:', error)` - Please do that, run the code again and post the full error stack (as text please).

Comment: (The reason for `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is that your server crashed by the way, so it's no longer listening on that port. Our goal now is to understand why it's crashing, and that's what we need the stack for.)

Comment: However, my psychic powers already tell me that it's probably because you are sending `owner` and `area` in your frontend but expect `newOwner` and `newArea` in your backend. You then proceed passing `newOwner` and `newArea` (which will both be `undefined`) into `gateway.connect` which will probably attempt to call `toString` on them and fail doing so. But whether this is true should become apparent from the stack (whether `gateway.connect` is in it or not).